# How do I sort my list of type class?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have a class that looks like this

```
class FeaturedListing 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Published { get; set; }
    public string Views { get; set; }
    public string Featured { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a list that looks like this

```
public static List<FeaturedListing> FeatiredListingsList = new List<FeaturedListing>();
```

After adding a few objects to that list, how do I properly sort by `Views`
views looks like this

`0 visits`
`52 visits`
`5 visits`
etc.

Comment: Here is one-liner: *var result = FeatiredListingsList.OrderBy(x=> int.Parse(x.Views.Split[' '][0])).ToList();*

Comment: I shall try it out!

Comment: Why is `Views` a string if you're storing integer data in it?

Comment: @eocron gave me this `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'`

Comment: Sorry, replace [] braces like this: *Split(' ')*

Comment: what order do you need? your example 0, 52, 5 is not a value order, neither an alphabetical one. In every case, being `Views` a string and not an integer smells a lot: why do you need to store these values as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [List.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) - Sorts the elements in the entire List using the specified System.Comparison..

```
void Main()
{
    var reatiredListingsList = new List<FeaturedListing>();
    reatiredListingsList.Add(new FeaturedListing{ Views = "0 Views"});
    reatiredListingsList.Add(new FeaturedListing{ Views = "52 Views"});
    reatiredListingsList.Add(new FeaturedListing{ Views = "5 Views"});

    reatiredListingsList.Sort((x, y) => {
        var xv = int.Parse(x.Views.Replace(" Views", ""));
        var yv = int.Parse(y.Views.Replace(" Views", ""));
        return xv < yv ? -1 : (xv > yv ? 1 : 0);
    });
}

class FeaturedListing
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Published { get; set; }
    public string  Views { get; set; }
    public string Featured { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the Views is a string that looks like this `0 Views` and `62 Views`

Comment: @MarkDenom well, it looked like a mistake in your description, and actually it should be an int if you want to compare it like this, regardless, I've updated the answer to use the Sort instead with converting to int before comparing. Also would be great to ready rules about downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to do an `OrderBy` on your `FeaturedListing.Views`.

```
var orderedList = FeatiredListingsList.OrderBy(x => x.Views).ToList();
```

However, if you're at liberty to change the structure of your program, you should really consider making `Views` an `int` so you can do proper numerical sorting. If you must, for some reason, output the value of `Views` as `0 visits`, `52 visits` etc, a better approach is to create a `get` only property in your `FeaturedListing` class like this:

```
public class FeaturedListing
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Published { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public string ViewsStr { get { return string.Format("{0} visits", Views); } }
    public string Featured { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: simply sorting by the string View will not work properly, assuming OP wants an order based on the value: if you compare strings, "102" < "14" <"51" < "6"